# Why is my key event not working when my code is added in wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, events

The following code works flawlessly here, but on WP not so much. When I inspect the console there are no errors.

```
$('input[name="tmp_post_tag"]').keypress(function(event) {

    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);   
    if (keycode == '13'){ 
        event.preventDefault();
        alert('You pressed a "enter" key in textbox');
    }    
});  

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
    <input type="text" 
            id="cant_use" 
            name="tmp_post_tag" 
            value="" 
            data-taxonomy="post_tag" 
            data-taxtype="flat" 
            class="wpt-new-taxonomy-title js-wpt-new-taxonomy-title form-control wpt-form-textfield form-textfield textfield"
            data-wpt-type="textfield" 
            data-wpt-id="cant_use" 
            data-wpt- autocomplete="off">

</form>
```

What am I doing wrong? FYI we are using input name because ID changes. Dont think thats the issue because it wirks here,

Comment: Works fine https://jsfiddle.net/exd3trpj/1/

Comment: Try putting your code in a document ready block

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress' own jQuery takes over the "`$`" variable, so you need to use "`jQuery`" instead, ie: `jQuery('input[name="tmp_post_tag"]').keypress(function(event) {`

Answer (score 0):

Might be content is generating dynamically, try using **on** function and keypress event inside it.

```
$('input[name="tmp_post_tag"]').on('keypress',function(event)
```